UISplitViewController layout difference between iOS 17 and iOS 18
I have a simple UISplitViewController layout of always visible primary and secondary columns.
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }

        // Create a UISplitViewController
        let splitViewController = UISplitViewController(style: .doubleColumn)
        splitViewController.preferredDisplayMode = .oneBesideSecondary
        splitViewController.presentsWithGesture = false

        // Set up primary and secondary view controllers
        let primaryVC = UIViewController()
        primaryVC.view.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        let secondaryVC = UIViewController()
        secondaryVC.view.backgroundColor = .systemGreen

        // Assign them to the split view controller
        splitViewController.setViewController(primaryVC, for: .primary)
        splitViewController.setViewController(secondaryVC, for: .secondary)

        // Set preferred width and min/max column width
        splitViewController.preferredPrimaryColumnWidth = 80
        splitViewController.minimumPrimaryColumnWidth = 80
        splitViewController.maximumPrimaryColumnWidth = 80

        // Initialize the window
        window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        window?.rootViewController = splitViewController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

It worked succesfully like that for my app for some time. However, I have seen some layouting issues on iOS18 and started to dig a bit deeper. It appears that something changed in UISplitViewController's structure between releases.
I'm running the follwing debuger command:
po splitViewController?.view.subviews.first?.subviews

On iPadOS 18:
<UILayoutContainerView: 0x10711dc50; frame = (80 0; 754 1210); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x6000000111b0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000024b500>>
<UILayoutContainerView: 0x105f0b280; frame = (-100 0; 180 1210); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600000008570>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000225a80>>
<UIPanelBorderView: 0x1071261f0; frame = (80 0; 0.5 1210); backgroundColor = UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 0 0.16; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000278b40>>

On iPadOS 17.5:
<UILayoutContainerView: 0x10630d990; frame = (80.5 0; 753.5 1210); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600000c665e0>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000266260>>
<UILayoutContainerView: 0x106206630; frame = (-100 0; 180 1210); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x600000c5d740>; layer = <CALayer: 0x60000022d820>>
<UIPanelBorderView: 0x106411e10; frame = (80 0; 0.5 1210); backgroundColor = <UIDynamicSystemColor: 0x600001764f40; name = opaqueSeparatorColor>; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000240900>>

In both cases we have 2 tab containers and a divider. However, on iOS 18 it appears that the divider is placed not by side but rather above the container view.
When attaching a view to the view.leadingAnchor or view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor of secondary view controller
on iPadOS 18 it goes behind the divider:

on iPadOS 17 it goes next to the divider:

Now, my question is, assuming that's not an Apple bug - is there way to get this 0.5px dimension of the divider in any elegant way? It doesn't seem to be reflected by safe area values or anything similar.
